# Customize stream playback paths in Red5 to access file from a shared machine

Tags: path, customization, directory, red5

I have installed Red5 server. I have created a custom application same as oflaDemo. I am able to play videos in /streams folder of my application, my application name is demo.I want to change the directory RED5_HOME/demo/webapps/streams from which my application is accessing videos, to a folder in a shared machine. I am able to change to a directory in local machine, for example "c:\streams". I have achieved this using CustomFileNameGenerator implementing IStreamFilenameGenerator . But I am not able to access a shared folder. Here is my CustomFileNameGenerator class

```
   import java.io.File;

   import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
   import org.red5.server.api.scope.IScope;
   import org.red5.server.api.stream.IStreamFilenameGenerator;


   public class CustomFilenameGenerator implements IStreamFilenameGenerator {

   Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CustomFilenameGenerator.class);

   /** Path that will store recorded videos. */
   /public String recordPath = "recordedStreams/";/
   /** Path that contains VOD streams. */
   public String playbackPath;



   /** Set if the path is absolute or relative */
   public Boolean resolvesAbsolutePath;


   public String generateFilename(IScope scope, String name, GenerationType type) {
   // Generate filename without an extension.
   return generateFilename(scope, name, null, type);

   }
   public String generateFilename(IScope scope, String name, String extension,               GenerationType type) {
   String filename = null;
   if (type == GenerationType.PLAYBACK)
   {
   filename = playbackPath + name;
   }
   log.info("file Name " + filename);
   if (extension != null)
   // Add extension
   filename += extension;
   log.info("Extension and file name " + filename);


   return filename;
   }
   public boolean resolvesToAbsolutePath()
   {

   log.info("resolvesAbsolutePath" + resolvesAbsolutePath);
   return resolvesAbsolutePath;
   }
   public void setPlaybackPath(String playbackPath) {
   this.playbackPath = playbackPath;
   }
   public void setResolvesAbsolutePath(Boolean resolvesAbsolutePath) {
   this.resolvesAbsolutePath = resolvesAbsolutePath;
   }



   }
```

Following are properties in my red5-web.properties file:

```
   webapp.contextPath=/demo
   webapp.virtualHosts=*, 192.168.1.20, 192.168.1.20:8088, 127.0.0.1:8088,       192.168.1.20:1935

   playbackPath=C://streams/
   resolvesAbsolutePath=true
```

Following is the bean definition in my red5-web.xml file

```
   <bean id="streamFilenameGenerator" class="com.abhinow.demo.CustomFilenameGenerator" >

   <property name="playbackPath" value="${playbackPath}" />
   <property name="resolvesAbsolutePath" value="${resolvesAbsolutePath}" />
   </bean>
```

The above given code is working fine and I am able to playback video in C:\streams folder, but when I have changed the playback path to a shared folder like
       /192.168.1.20/streams
it is not working. I am using windows computer. I have also tried by mapping shared folder        /192.168.1.20/streams to a network drive using map network drive feature in windows and gave name to that drive as Z:. Then I have tried by giving the path
       Z://streams
Now also it is not working.
Any one please help where I am getting it wrong. I have been struggling on it for two days. Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you debug if

```
generateFilename
```

is ever called in your application?
The first thing might be to add some log.debug statements to the code and having a look at the red5.log (or std.out).

Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> public String generateFilename(IScope scope, String name, String extension, GenerationType type) {
>   ...
>
> return playbackPath+filename;
>
> }

Comment: Code-only answers aren't all that helpful; consider adding a short explanation as to why your answer works.